# Set inherited Binding source for UserControl element

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Simple syntax question really but I'm getting nowhere:

(Psuedo code)

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<grid>
  <control:MyUserControl DataContext="{StaticResource MyDataSource}" />
</grid>
```

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<grid>
  <stackpanel DataContext="{StaticResource MyOtherDataSource}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanUseMe, Source={StaticResource MyDataSource}" />
</grid>
```

The problem is `{StaticResource MyDataSource}` in the stackpanel, since the user control doesn't have this resource.

How do I set the source binding to be the 'global' datasource passed into the usercontrol when I've already set the DataContext for the stackpanel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserControl`'s DataContext will be MyDataSource, so you can use `RelativeSource` in the Binding like this

```
<grid>
    <stackpanel DataContext="{StaticResource MyOtherDataSource}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                    Path=DataContext.CanUseMe}"/>
</grid>
```